# Blurring navigation bar

Tags: html, css, blur

My navigation bar is suppost to all be clear until you hover your mouse over a icon. Then all of the other icon should go blurred, but at the moment all of the icons are blurred to begin with. I cant figure out how to do this.
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/13722201/Dorset%20Designs/index.html

i believe you can view the css source as well if not ill post it.
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/13722201/Dorset%20Designs/main.css

Comment: Post your code here, in your question; and, ideally, post a live [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar, demo for us to see what you're doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with CSS3 (there are some browser limitations) and text-shadow + transitions

http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/sNQsy/ here is a quick demo (this will not be 100% cross browser .. ie for instance, I'll let you figure out how to fix that).

and here is the source code.

html

```
<ul class="nav">
<li><a href="#">link one</a></li>
<li><a href="#">link two</a></li>
<li><a href="#">link three</a></li>
<li><a href="#">link four</a></li>
<li><a href="#">link five</a></li>
</ul>​
```

css

```
.nav {
 list-style:none;    
}
.nav li {
 float: left;
 padding: 2px 12px;
}
.nav li a {
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 color: transparent;
 text-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.nav li:hover a {
 color: black;
 text-shadow: none; 
}​
```

[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/transition) is some info on transitions

[here is some more reading on css transforms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/transform) *they will interest you*

and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/text-shadow) on text shadows

Comment: your jsfiddle example is all blurred before you hover your mouse over it. is there a way to reverse this so that when you hover over the tex all other text is burred

Comment: But thankyou very much for the links they are very interesting

Comment: yes, switch the `color` and `text-shadow` properties on `.nav li a` and `nav li:hover a` respectively.